# Le mot « rentre-dedans » et son emploi

Tags: sens, expressions, mots-composés

Que veulent dire le mot *rentre-dedans* et la tournure « faire du rentre-dedans à quelqu’un » ? J’ai besoin d’un abrégé sur les emplois les plus usités de ce mot car les ressources que j’ai utilisées semblent se contredire.

J’ai lu que *rentre-dedans* peut être tant un nom commun qu’un adjectif. Selon les dictionnaires que j’ai utilisés, le nom commun désigne *un comportement menaçant* ou *fait de rentrer dans sa demeure*. Je ne sais encore rien de l'adjectif.

J’ai lu deux explications dissemblables de la phrase donnée plus haut.

- draguer quelqu’un avec instance
- flatter quelqu’un pour réussir à quelque chose

---

Si vous avez besoin des liens des ressources pour rédiger une réponse, laissez un commentaire, alors je vous en donne un résumé.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

L'expression « faire du rentre-dedans » est généralement utilisée pour décrire une méthode de séduction, d'approche (ou de « drague ») brusque, directe, explicite.
C'est un synonyme d'aguicher quelqu'un.

En voici une bonne définition : http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_du_rentre-dedans

Je n'ai pas connaissance d'un autre emploi de cette expression.

Comment: Celle ou celui qui *fait du rentre-dedans* a aussi un coté menaçant, dans le sens où il pense ne laisser aucune échappatoire à la personne qu'il vise et dont il veut obtenir quelque chose.

Comment: Je suis d'accord. D'ailleurs au sens littéral, "rentrer dedans" signifie bien faire intrusion dans l'espace personnel d'une personne. Instinctivement, c'est ressenti comme une menace.

Comment: J'utilise cette expression, peut-être à tort, pour ses aspects brusque et menaçant, sans la connotation de "séduction".

Comment: Oui à part "séduction" qui me parait aussi étrange...

Answer (score 3):

C'est une expression **familière** signifiant le fait de **tenter de séduire ou de draguer avec ostentation, voire avec brusquerie ou agression.**

**Exemple** : Toute la soirée, cette femme lui a fait du rentre-dedans.

On peut également **flatter ostensiblement quelqu'un dans le but d'obtenir un certain intérêt personnel et pas juste la séduction**.

**Exemple** : Je n'ai pas arrêté de lui faire du rentre-dedans pour pouvoir obtenir le sujet de l'examen.

Answer (score 3):

En complément, directement au dictionnaire :

> **Rentre-dedans**, subst. masc. a) *Boxe*. ,,Corps-à-corps`` (Esn. 1966). b) Pop. *Faire du rentre-dedans*. Faire des avances pressantes.
>   Synon. pop.  *gringue*. *Il me fait du rentre-dedans. Avec ça,
>   plaisant, bien élevé, et puis il avait de la conversation* (J.
>   Galtier-Boissière, *La Bonne vie*, 1925, p. 24 ds Cellard-Rey 1980).
>   *[Elle raconte] qu'il lui a fait du rentr'dedans, mais qu'elle est trop régulière* (Dussort, *Preuves exist*., 1927, dép. par Esnault,
>   1938, p. 71).
>
> [ *Trésor de la langue française informatisé* - « [*rentrer*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rentrer) » ]

Comparer généralement avec ce qu'on trouve à « dedans » :

> B.− Adv. de lieu. À l'intérieur :
>  − Loc. fig.
>   1. *Entrer, rentrer dedans*. Heurter quelqu'un, quelque chose avec violence. *Ils le gênaient, il ne pouvait pas s'approcher du comptoir
>   sans buter dedans* (Zola, *Assommoir*, 1877, p. 625). *Une voiture venant
>   de la droite m'est entrée, rentrée dedans* (Dub.1967).
>  ♦ Pop.
>   Assaillir, attaquer quelqu'un. *On va (...) devenir fous (...) Faut
>   leur rentrer dedans* (Malraux, *Espoir*, 1937, p. 481).
>
> [ *Trésor de la langue française informatisé* - « [*dedans*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dedans) » ]